# Reemplazar un caracter en una posicion especifica

Tags: javascript, string, caracteres, replace, console

Tengo una variable cuyo valor de asignación  es "El Arte de La Guerra";
Necesito reemplazar la 'e' de guerra por una 'a' que es el valor asignado a otra variable para que diga "El Arte de la Guarra." Estoy en JavaScript.

```
let tituloOriginial = "El Arte de La Guerra";
let cambioLetra = "a";
```

Comment: tituloOriginial.replace("e",cambioLetra )

Comment: Me cambiaria todas las letras 'e', no la posición y letra especifica de la palabra 'Guerra.'

Comment: Hagamos unsa cosa, lo pruebas y luego me dices si cambia todas las letras 'e' o si imprime El Arta de la Guerra  console.log(tituloOriginial.replace("e",cambioLetra ));

Comment: Efectivamente, Yussef. Me cambió todo por 'El Arta de La Guerra'

Comment: Sabes leí pésimo tu problema (mil disculpas) pensé que eso es lo que querías, ahora me fijo que es "Guarra".

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```js
const str = "El arte de la guerra"
const IndexCharacterToChange = str.lastIndexOf("e")
const newCharacter = "a"
const newStr = str.substring(0, IndexCharacterToChange) + newCharacter + str.substring(IndexCharacterToChange+1)
console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que son 4 las entradas

1. La oración
2. La cual tiene una palabra X que debe ser cambia una letra
3. La letra de la palabra a cambiar
4. La letra nueva que reemplaza a la antigua (3)

Entonces podría ser algo así:

```js
//función que cambia la primera letra de la primera palabra de una oracion
String.prototype.cambiar = function(palabra,letraVieja, LetraNueva){
  let palabras = this.split(" ");
  for(let p in palabras){
    if(palabras[p]===palabra){
      palabras[p]=palabra.replace(letraVieja,LetraNueva);
    }
  }
  return palabras.join(" ");
};

let tituloOriginial = "El Arte de La Guerra";
let cambioLetra = "a";

let nuevaOracion = tituloOriginial.cambiar("Guerra","e",cambioLetra);
console.log(nuevaOracion);
```

O otra manera mas burda

```js
let tituloOriginial = "El Arte de La Guerra";
let cambioLetra = "a";
console.log(  tituloOriginial.split("").reverse().join("").replace("e",cambioLetra).split("").reverse("").join("") );
```

Comment: Yussef, eres un genio! Muchas gracias, hermano. Saludos desde Cali, Colombia.

Comment: Interesante la utilización de un polyfill..